# como hago esta peticion en cURL de php 8

Tags: php, curl, php8, mercadolibre

se muy poco de este tipo de peticiones pero estoy intentando conectas las tiendas online que tenemos a MercadoLibre con php y me gustaría que me orientaran un poco en este tipo de petición PHP cURL, ya que dicen que la petición se realiza de esa forma pero no se como hacerlo en cURL.

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
'https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token' \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-d 'client_id=$APP_ID' \
-d 'client_secret=$SECRET_KEY' \
-d 'code=$SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE' \
-d 'redirect_uri=$REDIRECT_URI' \
-d 'code_verifier=$CODE_VERIFIER'
```

ejemplo de las consultas que e echo normalmente

```
    $url = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLV/search?nickname=MUSHERMOCA&offset=$result&limit=50";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

pero para hacer la de arriba no tnego ni idea como

```
$APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$SECRET_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$REDIRECT_URI = "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com";
$CODE_VERIFIER = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";


$url = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    'accept: application/json',
    'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


$data = array(
    'grant_type=authorization_code'
  .'&client_id='.urlencode($APP_ID)
  .'&client_secret='.urlencode($SECRET_KEY)
  .'&code='.urlencode($SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
  .'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($REDIRECT_URI)
  .'&code_verifier='.urlencode($CODE_VERIFIER
 )); 


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);




$objetos = json_decode($data, true);

var_dump($objetos);
```

cuando hago el vardunp me genera el siguiente error

```
array(4) { ["message"]=> string(34) "grant_type is a required parameter" ["error"]=> string(15) "invalid_request" ["status"]=> int(400) ["cause"]=> array(0) { } }
```

y si coloco la misma linea de comando de aca abajo con los datos en postman me da el json con los resultados sin problemas

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
'https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token' \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-d 'client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx' \
-d 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx' \
-d 'code=xxxxxxxxxx' \
-d 'redirect_uri=xxxxxxxxxxx' \
-d 'code_verifier=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: en curl se hace exactamente como la publicaste.

Comment: en php disculpa, ya edito la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para entender lo que le falta y sobra a lo que ya haces, primero debes entender el comando que encontraste en el ejemplo.

Al ejecutar curl en la línea de comandos, los [modificadores](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) que encontramos son:

- [`-H`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-H), establece un header
- [`-d`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d), establece un *dato* a enviar en un request tipo POST.

El equivalente en `curl` para PHP sería llamar a [`curl_setopt`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php) con las opciones:

- `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, que debe recibir:

  > Un array de campos a configurar para el header HTTP, en el formato: `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`
- `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, que debe recibir

  > Todos los datos para enviar vía HTTP "POST"
  > ...
  > Se puede enviar una cadena urlencoded como `'para1=val1&para2=val2&...'`

En ambos casos, la llamada de línea de comandos va agregando los headers y datos individuales uno a uno, mientras la llamada en PHP debe pasarlos todos en un solo arreglo.

Así, suponiendo que las variables correctas están en su lugar, la llamada podría traducirse en algo como:

```
//inicializar las variables necesarias, por ejemplo leyendolas de un objeto de configuración:

$APP_ID = $cfg->appid;
$SECRET_KEY = $cfg->secretkey;
//etc. Todas las variables deben estar inicializadas o usar constantes

$url = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    'accept: application/json',
    'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = 
    'grant_type=authorization_code'
   .'&client_id='.urlencode($APP_ID)
   .'&client_secret='.urlencode($SECRET_KEY)
   .'&code='.urlencode($SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
   .'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($REDIRECT_URI)
   .'&code_verifier='.urlencode($CODE_VERIFIER)

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Dado que desconozco el tipo de información que hay en esas variables, estoy yendo por la vía segura llamando a [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) con cada una y así asegurarme que los datos van bien codificados en caso de haber caracteres especiales, espacios, etc.

Advertencia: He escrito el código aquí mismo en la respuesta, puede contener algún error, pero entendiendo la idea y con ayuda de la documentación puedes producir una versión funcional. En todo caso, si hay errores o algo no funciona, dejame un comentario y vemos de que se trata.

**Edición**: Había un error en la respuesta original, pues enviaba incorrectamente los datos del post como `multipart/form-data`, mientras el header decía que iban en `x-www-urlencoded`.

El extracto de la documentación original relacionado a `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` era:

> Todos los datos para enviar vía HTTP "POST"
> ...
> como un array con el nombre del campo como key y los datos como value

Que justo después dice:

> Si value es un array, el encabezado Content-Type será definido como multipart/form-data

Por lo tanto, hay que pasar un string con la forma adecuada. El código de la respuesta original era este:

```
$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
  , 'client_id' => $APP_ID
  , 'client_secret' => $SECRET_KEY
  , 'code' => $SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE
  , 'redirect_uri' => $REDIRECT_URI
  , 'code_verifier' => $CODE_VERIFIER
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Lo dejo aquí si alguien en el futuro llega a este punto tratando de hacer un POST en `multipart/form-data`, seguro le puede ser útil. También para resolver la misma confusión que había en la respuesta original.

Comment: hola amigo, disculpa que demore en responder, efectivamente veo todo bien pero me da un error


array(4) { ["message"]=> string(34) "grant_type is a required parameter" ["error"]=> string(15) "invalid_request" ["status"]=> int(400) ["cause"]=> array(0) { } }

y gracias por la explicación ya voy entendiendo a que hacia referencia el -H y -d que no entendía

Comment: amigo, edite la pregunta y te copie como estoy colocando el código a ver si le ves el error, por que no logro obtener los datos, y los valores que estoy colocando en la secret , app id y lo demás, están bien por que hago la solicitud en postman con los datos y me da bien el json pero cuando la hago por el php nada aun que el var_dump me da el json, si le puedes revisar a eso te lo agradezco por favor.

Comment: listo amigo ese era el error, muchas gracias